# Use a function to create variables with mutate in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I have the following code

```
library(dplyr)
p <- data.frame(a = rep(0:2, times = 5)) %>%
       mutate(a1 = a == 1,a2 = a == 2)
```

I want to put the expressions in `mutate`in a function (or a list, I do not really care) so that I define them before running `mutate`

I tried this:

```
mutatemy=function(){
  (a1=a==1,a2=a==2)
}

p <- data.frame(a = rep(0:2, times = 5)) %>%
mutate(mutatemy())
```

which does not work of course.

Ideally, I should be able to flexibly put all possible `mutate` combinations such as the use of `across`.

How could I achieve this.

The background is that I mutate inside a function and I want the user to allow specifying exactly what to mutate without manipulating the function.

Here is a simplified example of what I want to eventually achieve.

```
mainfunction <- function(data=data){

#somecode...

data2<- data %>% mutate(r=a*a, # hardcoded 
                        userinput) # here I want to allow the user to decide what else to mutate
return(data2)
}

## user supplies data
data= data.frame(data.frame(a=rep(0:2,times=5))

## and the desired manipulations based on the supplied dataset
userinput <- (a1=a==1)

## and then applies this function
mainfunction(data)

#somecode...
```

Thanks a lot! Julian

Comment: There are alot of things wrong with this. First, why would you want to hard code outside mutate? If at all you have changing variables then you rinterest should be how to program with mutate.

Comment: This works 

```expr2 <- list(a1 = expr( a==1),
              a2= expr( a==2))
p=data.frame(a=rep(0:2,times=5)) %>% 
  mutate(!!! expr2) ```

But it still does not allow me to use `across`

Comment: Still the question is why would you want to hard code outside mutate? WHat are you trying to solve?

Comment: sorry, I tried to explain in the edited question now.

Comment: Hi Julian! It might be helpful to come up with a real toy example of what you want. I can think of quite a few different answers which might be the one you want, but it's unclear right now which one that might be. @Onyambu is right, this is quite odd

Comment: In your example with the list of expressions, the only input column `a` is hard-coded - it's not at all clear what `across()` would do here, as `across` is generally used select inputs. I strongly agree with the other commenters that this example doesn't seem to illustrate your problem well.

Comment: @GregorThomas: You can also use it to make many variables at the same time, e.g. 
`across(.cols=1:3,.fns = ~ rgumbel(setpp,loc=0, scale=1), .names = "{'e'}_{1:3}" )` and this is what I want the user to specify. Additionally to the fixed procedures the data processing in the function is doing, the user can manipulate variables.

Comment: If you want the user to be able to pass though addition transformations, consider passing them along with `...`. That's described at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: @JulianSagebiel Yes, you can use `across` to make many variables at once. But your `expr2` example doesn't do that either... it hardcodes both the columns tested and resulting column names. Can you show an example with `across` where `across` does something?

Comment: I want to give a completely new example and explanation for my problem, but I am not sure what the correct behavior is. Shall I just edit my initial question (which means it will be to 80% new) or shall I post the problem in a new answer or new thread? Sorry for this noop question.